# converting accelerometer/gyroscope values to x/y

Tags: javascript, css, accelerometer, mousemove, gyroscope

I'm using document.mousemove to animate a gradient. I'd like to use the same function on mobile devices with an accelerometer/gyroscope, but I can't seem to translate the values.

I've tried various equations but can't seem to get things to work.

Here's my JS:

```
$(document).mousemove(function(event) {
    windowWidth = $(window).width();
    windowHeight = $(window).height();

    mouseXpercentage = Math.round(event.pageX / windowWidth * 100);
    mouseYpercentage = Math.round(event.pageY / windowHeight * 100);

    $('.radial-gradient').css('background', 'radial-gradient(at ' + mouseXpercentage + '% ' + mouseYpercentage + '%, #72c0d4, #03373d)');
});
```